# Запуск скрипта через psql на сервере Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

Есть большой скрипт с миллионом записей, **script123.sql** Он был загружен на сервер **Ubuntu 14.04** на котором крутится **postgresql 9.4**, с машины windows, через winscp. При запуске psql из под windows машины(которая входит в состав PGAdmin III) при попытке загрузить скрипт через команду `\i script123.sql` выводится ошибка, об отсутствии файла: `script123.sql No such file or directory`, как при указании и относительных путей так и прямых:

```
\i /home/user/script123.sql
/home/user/script123.sql No such file or directory

\i ../script123.sql
/home/user/script123.sql No such file or directory
```

Куда нужно скопировать этот скрипт, чтобы его можно было запустить из psql (windows)? В Windows достаточно скопировать скрипт в: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\data . Пробовал скопировать "по аналогии" в **/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main** и **/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/** - не помогает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> При запуске psql из под windows машины

\i - это команда именно клиента psql, читать файл может только с локальной машины, с той, на которой запущен psql, а сервер postgresql может быть где угодно.

Поэтому если вы хотите запустить psql на клиенте, то и файл должен быть расположен где-то на клиенте.